Why my code work well in local but runtime error (signed int overflowed) in Leetcode?
The problem link: https://leetcode.com/problems/combination-sum-iv/description/
Given an array of distinct integers nums and a target integer target, return the number of possible combinations that add up to target.
The test cases are generated so that the answer can fit in a 32-bit integer.
This is my code by C++:
class Solution {
public:
    int combinationSum4(vector<int>& nums, int target) {
        vector<int> dp(target + 1, 0);
        dp[0] = 1;
        for (int i = 1; i <= target; ++i){
            for (int num : nums) {
                if (i >= num) {
                    dp[i] += dp[i - num];
                }
            }
        }
        return dp[target];
    }
};

The error:
Line 9: Char 27: runtime error: signed integer overflow: 2147483647 + 1 cannot be represented in type 'value_type' (aka 'int') (solution.cpp)
SUMMARY: UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer: undefined-behavior solution.cpp:9:27
But when I try to run on my local, it's work well.
Can anyone can help me? Thank a lotttt!!!!
The image here

Provide a [mcve].

Signed integer overflow is undefined behavior. You don't have any guaranteed behavior at all with undefined behavior.  It seemingly working is a valid outcome. Leetcode is not suitable to learn C++ as a programming language, otherwise you would have learned that early on when learning about arithmetic operators.

Don't post text in images, post text as text in a code block. I would answer and help you, but I can't copy text in the picture and you have not make a [mre].

Side notes, mentioning leetcode (or showing the "Solution class") is not helping. (Leetcode is considered to be a bad influence for good C++ coding practices).  Advice : learn C++ first before you start doing competitive coding, e.g. visit learncpp.com

The problem statement only guarantees that the answer is guaranteed to be representable in a 32-bit integer. Intermediate states that are not used in calculating the result for target thus may not be representable and can overflow. To avoid this, you could use a top down dynamic programming solution instead, which never calculates answers for unnecessary states.
int combinationSum4(vector<int>& nums, int target) {
    vector<int> dp(target + 1, -1);
    dp[0] = 1;
    auto solve = [&](const auto& self, int t) -> int {
        if (dp[t] == -1) {
            dp[t] = 0;
            for (int num : nums)
                if (t >= num) dp[t] += self(self, t - num);
        }
        return dp[t];
    };
    return solve(solve, target);
}


Or use vector<unsigned int> dp

@3CxEZiVlQ That really just hides the issue since there's no warning for wraparound but the calculated value for intermediate states would still be incorrect.

target+1 might also overflow.

@Jarod42 The constraints state that 1 <= target <= 1000.

Well if you check the constraints you would got the solution. 
std::vector<int64_t> dp(target + 1, 0); 
-> This changes the data type of dp to int64_t, which can handle much larger numbers than int. 
Try this one it will work.

That doesn't answer the question of why OP observes the behavior that they do.

Same issue: /app/example.cpp:14:17: runtime error: signed integer overflow: 8728396699775797888 + 4368502481912840752 cannot be represented in type 'value_type' (aka 'long')
